# Object Recognition in OpenCV with Python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img = cv.imread("photo1.jpg")
print(img)

img_width = img.shape[1]
img_height = img.shape[0]

img_blob = cv.dnn.blobFromImage(img,1/255,(416,416),swapRB = True)
lables = ["person", "bicycle", "car", "motorcycle", "airplane", "bus", "train", "truck", "boat",
          "trafficlight", "firehydrant", "stopsign", "parkingmeter", "bench", "bird", "cat",
          "dog", "horse", "sheep", "cow", "elephant", "bear", "zebra", "giraffe", "backpack",
          "umbrella", "handbag", "tie", "suitcase", "frisbee", "skis", "snowboard", "sportsball",
          "kite", "baseballbat", "baseballglove", "skateboard", "surfboard", "tennisracket",
          "bottle", "wineglass", "cup", "fork", "knife", "spoon", "bowl", "banana", "apple",
          "sandwich", "orange", "broccoli", "carrot", "hotdog", "pizza", "donut", "cake", "chair",
          "sofa", "pottedplant", "bed", "diningtable", "toilet", "tvmonitor", "laptop", "mouse",
          "remote", "keyboard", "cellphone", "microwave", "oven", "toaster", "sink", "refrigerator",
          "book", "clock", "vase", "scissors", "teddybear", "hairdrier", "toothbrush"]

colors = ["255,255,0","0,255,0","255,0,255","0,255,255","0,0,255"]
colors = [np.array(color.split(",")).astype("int") for color in colors]
colors = np.array(colors)
colors = np.tile(colors,(20,1))

model = cv.dnn.readNetFromDarknet ("Model/yolov3.cfg","Model/yolov3.weights")
layers = model.getLayerNames()
output_layer = [layers[layer[0]-1] for layer in model.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]

model.setInput(img_blob)

detection_layers = model.forward(output_layer)

ids_list = []
boxes_list = []
confidences_list = []

for detection_layer in detection_layers:
    for object_detection in detection_layer:
        scores = object_detection[5:]
        predicted_id = np.argmax(scores)
        confidence = scores[predicted_id]

        if confidence > 0.80:
            label = lables[predicted_id]
            bounding_box = object_detection[0:4] * np.array(img_width,img_height,img_width,img_height)
            (box_center_x, box_center_y,box_width,box_height) = bounding_box.astype("int")

            start_x = int(box_center_x - (box_width/2))
            start_y = int(box_center_y - (box_height/2))

            ids_list.append(predicted_id)
            confidences_list.append(float(confidence))
            boxes_list.append([start_x,start_y,int(box_width),int(box_height)])

max_ids = cv.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes_list,confidences_list,0.5,0.4)

for max_id in max_ids:
    max_class_id = max_id[0]
    box = boxes_list[max_class_id]

    start_x = box[0]
    start_y = box[1]
    box_width = box[2]
    box_height = box[3]

    predicted_id = ids_list[max_class_id]
    label = lables[predicted_id]
    confidence = confidences_list[max_class_id]

    end_x = start_x + box_width
    end_y = start_y + box_height

    box_color = colors[predicted_id]
    box_color = [int(each)for each in box_color]

    cv.rectangle(img,(start_x,start_y),(end_x,end_y),box_color,2)
    cv.putText(img,label,(start_x,start_y-20),cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.5,box_color,1)

cv.imshow("Detection Screen", img)
```

I am getting the following error in this code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bahac\OneDrive\Desktop\OpenCV\main.py", line 29, in <module>
    output_layer = [layers[layer[0]-1] for layer in model.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bahac\OneDrive\Desktop\OpenCV\main.py", line 29, in <listcomp>
    output_layer = [layers[layer[0]-1] for layer in model.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
                           ~~~~~^^^
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

I'm working on object recognition in OpenCV with Python, but I ran into an error in the code.

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the value of "layer" (or its first element). I recommend getting the return value for `model.getUnconnectedOutLayers()` first and validating its contents before using it in a list comprehension, which here makes it harder to debug.